# Cannot Connect to SQL Server after hosting the app on heroku

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, heroku

I'm using mssql along with node.
I call a function to connect to the database:

```
const sql = require('mssql')
async () => {
   try {
      const pool = await sql.connect(`mssql://${process.env.DATAUSER}:${process.env.DATAPASS}@${process.env.SERVER}`)
   } catch(err) {
       console.log(err)
   }
}
```

This works perfectly fine when i'm on a localhost but after i've hosted it to heroku and add the env variables. The error I get is (I changed the ip address to 5's):

```
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 55.5.5.555:1433 in 15000ms
```

My process.env.SERVER = 55.5.5.555/SpecificDatabase and If that means anything

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reference to your specific database or schema in this code. It may be possible that your local implementation of the data server differs from the heroku implementation in respect to the default schema or database to which a user is directed. Therefore, you may need to add a database or schema field to your connection call.

For example, my pool code to connect to the OSU server is:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'classmysql.engr.oregonstate.edu',
  user            : 'username',
  password        : 'password',
  database        : 'database_name',
  multipleStatements: true
});
module.exports.pool = pool;
```

Though my implementation here was with mysql and not mssql, it may hold true that you need to explicitly name a specific database or schema.